# Visual Studio plugin which shows using of symbol in a contextmenu

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Is there any Visual Studio (or Resharper) Plugin, which shows the usings of a symbol in a context menu?

So I can move my cursor above a symbol, hit a shortcut to open the context menu, select an entry with the arrow keys and then jump to the position of the using?

I know there is a tab which shows the usings, but navigating using this feature costs a lot of time and annoys me.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper has a function for that.

```
Resharper.Resharper_GotoUsage
```